# Python - Check with regex the two first digits of a user input number

Tags: python

How can I check with regex if the two first digits of a user input number match 33?

Comment: Why use a regex? Simply use `.startswith('33')`.

Comment: thanks Willem . I've already test it with .startswith and works. I want to test it additionally with regex

Comment: also you can use list slicing like : `a = input(); a[:2] == '33'`

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

pattern = "^33"                     # ^ means begin of the string
pattern = re.compile(pattern)
if pattern.search(YourUserInput):
    # Your code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

if re.match('^33', s):
     print "String %s starts with 33..." % s
```

Comment: it worked the proposed re methods and the slice one! thanks to all of you guys!!